# How can I determine which particle system is hitting the player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, parameters

So I have many particle systems (Spells) that are going to be hitting the player. How can I set it so that I can tell which particle system is hitting the player and then apply the correct damage from there? Would I have to do something like

```
void OnParticleCollision(collider particle1)
{
 float damage = 50;
 TakeDamage(damage);
}
```

and then do that like 50 times? There has to be a simpler way.

To go a little further we'll say spell 1 should do 50 damage, spell 2 should do 100 damage, spell 3 should do 200 damage, and spell 4 should do 50 damage, just to overlap a little. Obviously it will have more than 4, I just don't know how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the particle system has a certain component. Like the following:

```
    void OnParticleCollision(collider particle1) {
        Spell1 spell1 = particle1.gameobject.GetComponent<Spell1>();
        if (spell1) {
           float damage = 50;
           TakeDamage(damage);
        }
    }
```